# Higher order javascript functions

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, higher-order-functions

can someone explain to me what is going on in the following code. The function is receiving `n` as parameter, so where is the `m` coming from? The whole code is confusing.. if someone can explain?

```
  function greaterThan(n) {
  return function(m) { return m > n; };
  }
   var greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
   console.log(greaterThan10(11));
   // → true
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is exhibiting a functional programming technique called [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). (related also to [partial function appliction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application))

Greater than `>` usually takes 2 arguments (one on the left and one on the right).  This is a way to feed one at a time.

It might be easier to see what is happening if you call it inline:

```
greaterThan(10)(11);
```

As you can see from the example above, the `10` gets passed in for the `n` parameter and then the `11` gets passed in for the `m` parameter.

The first application that passes the `10` outputs a function that looks like this:

```
function(m) { return m > 10; };
```

This is the first *application* in the partial application.

From there it is easy to see how the `11` is passed in to get the final result.

So, to break it down:

```
function greaterThan(n) {
   return function(m) { return m > n; };
}

//var greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10); -- is equivalent to:
var greaterThan10 = function(m) { return m > 10; };

console.log(greaterThan10(11));  //--> true
```

Answer (score 6):

`m` is `11`, passed in during the second call.

When you call `greaterThan(10)`, it returns a new function that looks like:

```
function(m) {
    return m > 10;
}
```

which is then saved as `greaterThan10`. This is called [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Answer (score 2):

`greaterThan` is a function that returns another function as a result, `m` is a paraterer of that returned function. So in your code:
`var greaterThan10 = function(m) { return m > 10; };`

and 
`console.log(greaterThan10(11));` is the same as `console.log(11 > 10);`

Answer (score 2):

when you call function `greaterThan` it returns another function but not a number of float. Inner function knows about `n` because it inside function `greaterThan`.

Because wrapper function returns another function you can call second one like this

```
var result = greaterThan(10)(11);
```

first argument `10` will be used for wrapper function but result is function so you can pass arguments for inner function immediately. 
this is possible only if you have `return function(){...}`

you can try something like

```
var a = function (x){
         return function(y){
            return function(z){
              return x*y*z;
            }
          }
        }
var result = a(5)(3)(8);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two functions there.

The `n` comes from when the first function is called.

The `m` comes from when the second function (which is the return value of the first function) is called.

```
greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
//                          ^^  n
greaterThan10(11))
//  ^^ returned function
//            ^^ m
```